# Dyke improvement

Tags: civil-engineering

I'm a civil engineering student, and it's my first year at the University of Applied Sciences, and I'm doing an exercise but can't figure out one of its parts.

The question: what are the advantages and disadvantages of reinforcement outside the dikes?

So far I've found only general information about dyke improvement, and not the specific information about the disadvantages and advantages.

So any information related to this question by any of you will be helpful for me to be able to understand it and answer the question correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! I've edited your question to remove a lot of the description of your course. Just knowing you're a first-year student already gives us a good understanding of your level. One question: is the question you've written a direct copy of the actual question? I ask because "... reinforcement outside ***the*** dikes" makes it seem like this question is about a specific case (real or fictional), not a general question about the pros/cons of reinforcement outside of dikes in general. If this is about a specific case, please [edit] your question with any relevant details.

Comment: @Wasabi thank you for the support. As far as I know It's a general question, so no specific case is linked to this question.